# How to view catalogue of static files on GAE control panel?

Tags: google-app-engine

How may I view the catalogue of static files on the GAE control panel, or some other way in a browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such functionality on GAE.

You will need to look at your project's source. If this is not available, you could try to [download project source](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#Downloading_Source_Code). Note that this could be disabled.